# TextPad Find Replace Commands Wild Cards

Tags: textpad

I am trying to figure out how I can put together a find and replace command with wildcards or figure out a way to find and replace the following example:

I would like to find terms that contain double quotes in front of them with a single quote at the end:

Example: 
find "joe' and replace with 'joe'

Basically, I'm trying to find all terms with terms having "in front and at the end.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `[x] Regular expression` checkbox in textpad's replace dialog and enter the following values:

Find what:

```
"([^'"]*)'
```

Replace with:

```
'\1'
```

Explanation:

In a regular expression, square brackets are used to indicate character classes. A character class beginning with a caret will match anything not in the class.
Thus `[^'"]` will match any character except `'` and `"`.  The following `*` indicates that any number of these characters can follow. The `(` and `)` mark a group. And the group we're looking for starts with `"` and ends with `'`. Finally in the replace string we can refer to any group via `\n` where n is the nth group. In our case it is the first and only group and that is why we used `\1`.

Comment: How can I additionally have it search for single quote with either a , or ; (comma or semicolon) in front of the single quote?

Comment: I'm note quite sure what you mean. Give an example string please.

Comment: Search for `"([^'"]*)'([,;])` and, assuming you want to keep the `; ,` you'd replace it with `'\1'\2`